# Convertir objeto java a map

Tags: java

Tengo un objeto que tiene unos 60 atributos que son tanto de tipo String como de tipo double, además de unos cuantos que son de otros tipos, y por azares del destino necesito un map en donde las keys sean los nombres de los atributos del objeto y value sus valores, sin embargo quiero poder también escoger que atributos de ese objeto no deben convertirse a map, es decir solo quiero que los que son de tipo String y double se pasen al map.

Comment: Suena un tanto vago y un poco complicado. ¿Quieres que la conversión a `Map` sea superficial o profunda? En caso de ser profunda, ¿cómo debe soportar las referencias cíclicas? ¿Cómo se deberían convertir las colecciones en el mapa? ¿Qué sucede si hay elementos que no son serializables? ¿Debería ser `Map<String, String>` o `Map<String, Object>`? ¿Has considerado mejor serializar la información en un formato como JSON y luego deserializarlo como `Map`?

Comment: No quiero que sea profunda, solo me interesan realmente los atributos de tipo String y double y no, no había pensado en serializarlo, investigaré un poco más

Comment: Agregar más contexto sobre el problema ayudaría a comprender mejor tu situación y proveer una respuesta. De momento, si quieres evitar la parte de serialización y deserialización (puesto que consume tiempo de ejecución), entonces podrías hacer un prototipo base usando reflexión para convertir solamente los atributos de tipo `String` y `double` (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví usando Jackson con lo siguiente :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, Object> atributosGuiaFedex = 
        mapper.convertValue(guiaFedex, Map.class);
    System.out.println(atributosGuiaFedex);
```

En donde guiaFedex es el objeto que quiero convertir a map y para ignorar los atributos coloqué lo siguiente hasta arriba de la clase que quisé convertir:

> ```
> @JsonIgnoreProperties({"guia","periodo","id","fechaEnvio","cargosDeGuiaAerea"})
> ```

en donde lo que está entre comillas son los atributos a ignorar.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes haces es convertir tu clase en un `Iterator` para poder iterar sobre sus atributos, cuando se itere debes condicionar si es `string o double`

```
if (atributo instanceof String) {
  esCadena = (String) atributo;
}
```